# "f2py not found" when trying to run from command line

Tags: python, path, f2py

I tried using f2py today (in Terminal, on a Mac running High Sierra) and got the following message:

```
-bash: f2py: command not found
```

This is especially weird because I used f2py a few months ago with no problem; the only thing I can think of that's changed is updating my OS.

Some hunting online suggested that the path to numpy might not be listed in my PATH variable.  I found the f2py folder was in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/
```

So I added `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to the PATH definition in .bashrc (and checked that $PATH was actually updated); no dice.  I then thought I'd get even more specific in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/share/python/:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/f2py/
```

I did the same with PYTHONPATH.  Still no dice; I'm getting the same message.

A couple of other things that may or may not be of use:

1. When I use the command `echo $PYTHONPATH$`, it just gives me the list I defined with .bashrc, but when I print sys.path from python, it gives me a much longer list, including

   ```
   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   ```

   as well as

   ```
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
   ```

   (possibly relevant for point #2)
2. When I tried to run f2py using

   python f2py.py

   I got the message

   ```
   /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'f2py.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
   ```

At this point, I'm pretty stumped--I don't know a ton about how all these paths work but I feel like I'm pointing everything towards the right directory and it still can't find f2py.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Additional info:
After posting this, I realized that the directories in PATH are searched in order, so I made sure the directory with my desired python installation was listed first.  Unfortunately, that still didn't help.

Comment: what does `which f2py` yield

Comment: Nothing at all; just the next blank line on the command line. :/

Comment: `fp2y` is a standalone executable and should technically be in the `bin` folder of your PYTHON installation

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has the same problem: I still don't know the cause, but somehow my python installation was very messed up.  I had installed via homebrew, so I just uninstalled python through brew (and scipy and numpy as well), downloaded the latest version of the Canopy distribution, and made sure to update PATH to point to the folder Canopy uses (for a Mac, it's `/Users/<user>/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/bin`).  Now f2py is working again, thank goodness!